# Why is my sprite not being drawn correctly (libgdx)?

Tags: android, libgdx, sprite

I have a 1024x1024 pixel image in a jpg file. I am trying to render it onscreen with libgdx such that it fills the whole screen. At this stage I am not concerned with the image preserving its aspect ratio.

In my show() method I parse the jpg and initialize the sprite thus:

```
mWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
mHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

mCamera = new OrthographicCamera(1, mHeight/mWidth);
mBatch = new SpriteBatch();

mTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("my jpg file"));

mTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion(mTexture);

mSprite = new Sprite(region);
mSprite.setSize(0.99f, 0.99f);
mSprite.setOrigin(mSprite.getWidth()/2, mSprite.getHeight()/2);
mSprite.setPosition(-mSprite.getWidth()/2, -mSprite.getHeight()/2);
```

and in the render() method, I draw the sprite thus

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

mBatch.setProjectionMatrix(mCamera.combined);
mBatch.begin();
mSprite.draw(mBatch);
mBatch.end();
```

but all that is actually rendered is a blank white screen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should use

   ```
   mCamera = new OrthographicCamera(mWidth, mHeight);
   ```

   in stead of

   ```
   mCamera = new OrthographicCamera(1, mHeight/mWidth);
   ```

   in most cases, unless you want to scale things in a different way.
2. Check if your code has actually found and read the file successfully. If not, check things like full path, file extension, intermediate spaces etc.
3. In resize method, try adding following

   ```
   mBatch.getProjectionMatrix().setToOrtho2D(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);
   ```
4. If it isn't working even then, I'd recommend falling back to the working libgdx logo sprite being drawn when you create a new project with setup ui. Change things slowly from there.

For reference, use https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/Sprites

Good luck.

Comment: I would not use the PhysicalScreen size/ size of the window for the camera viewport. Different devices have different sizes and so you would then need to calculate the positions in a different way. Instead i would use a fixed viewport (lets say `160, 100`), so you can calculate in your own unit (maybe meters) instead of pixels. By doing this, it doesn't how big your window is, you always have 160 units in x-direction and 100 in y.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, `mSprite.setSize(0.99f, 0.99f);` sets the pixel width and height of a sprite whereas `setScale` scales the sprite's dimensions. Setting `setSize` to something larger such as 256 x 256 should make your sprite visible and setting it to the resolution of the screen should make it fill the screen if all goes well. The examples linked by Tanmay Patil are great so look into them if you're having trouble.